# Listing all related details of a model object through Django ORM

Tags: python, performance, mysql, django

How can my solution be improved / optimized?

***explaination of db models :***
*thinkpad* is a `equipment` of *laptop* `subcategory`.and *laptop subcategory* has a `category` called *electronics*.
now *laptop* can have many `attributes` like `processor,ram,color,screen_size`.

***Question :***
Find out all the `equipments` with their`equipment detail ,subcategory_name and attribute names,value`  which have *category_id =1* .

***Desired Output:***

```
[ 
   { 
      'equipment_id':1,
      'subcategory__name':'laptop',
      'attribute_detail':[ 
         { 
            'attribute_name':'color',
            'attribute_value':'red'
         },
         { 
            'attribute_name':'ram',
            'attribute_value':'6gb'
         }
      ]
   },
   {   'equipment_id':2,
      'subcategory__name':'Mouse',
      'attribute_detail':[ 
         { 
            'attribute_name':'color',
            'attribute_value':'red'
         },
         { 
            'attribute_name':'dpi',
            'attribute_value':'800'
         }
      ]
    }

]
```

***Solution:***

```
equipments = Equipment.objects.filter(subcategory__category__category_id=1)  


all_equipments_data = []  

# iterate over each equipment  

for equipment in equipments:
    single_equipment_data = {}  
    single_equipment_data['equipment_id'] = equipment.equipment_id
    single_equipment_data['subcategory__name'] = equipment.subcategory.subcategory_name  

    attributes_detail_of_equipment = []  

# iterate over each equipmentdetail of single equipment

    for eqdetail in equipment.equipment_eqdetail.all(): 
        single_attribute_detail_of_equipment = {}  
        single_attribute_detail_of_equipment['attribute_name'] = eqdetail.attribute.attribute_name
        single_attribute_detail_of_equipment['attribute_value'] = eqdetail.value  

        attributes_detail_of_equipment.append(single_attribute_detail_of_equipment)  

        single_equipment_data['attribute_detail'] = attributes_detail_of_equipment  

all_equipments_data.append(single_equipment_data)
```

***Models :***

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, default=None)
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.category_id)+","+self.category_name

    class Meta:
        db_table = "category"


class Subcategory(models.Model):
    subcategory_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, default=None)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="category_subc", verbose_name="category_id")
    subcategory_name = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.subcategory_id)+","+self.subcategory_name

    class Meta:
        db_table = "subcategory"


class Equipment(models.Model):
    equipment_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, default=None)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(
        Subcategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="subcategory_eq", verbose_name="subcategory_id")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.equipment_id)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "equipment"


class Attribute(models.Model):
    attribute_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, default=None)
    attribute_name = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    subcategory = models.ManyToManyField(
        Subcategory, through="SubcategoryAttributeMap")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.attribute_id)+","+self.attribute_name

    class Meta:
        db_table = "attribute"


class SubcategoryAttributeMap(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, default=None)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(
        Subcategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="subcategory_sub_attr_map", verbose_name="subcategory_id")
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(
        Attribute, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="attribute_sub_attr_map", verbose_name="attribute_id")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "subcategory_attribute_map"


class EquipmentDetail(models.Model):
    equipment_detail_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, default=None)
    equipment = models.ForeignKey(
        Equipment, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="equipment_eqdetail", verbose_name="equipment_id")
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(
        Attribute, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="attribute_eqdetail", verbose_name="attribute_id")
    value = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.equipment_detail_id)+","+self.value

    class Meta:
        db_table = "equipment_detail"
```

Comment: Hey Naveen, please edit your title to state what your code does. Asking questions in the title makes it difficult for users to be interested in the question.

Comment: @IEatBagels i have updated the title , but i dont understand why downvote when everything seems proper

Comment: Don't worry about a single downvote. Your post is good, it'll attract the votes and the answers :)